# Add class="act-link" to active page - PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have simple code in HTML page:

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php BASE_URL; ?>/index.php" class="<?php echo $Home; ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php BASE_MEMBERS; ?>/index.php" class="<?php echo $Users; ?>">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php BASE_URL; ?>/contact.php" class="<?php echo $Contact; ?>">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Note: ( **In config file**)

*BASE_URL =* `<?php define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost'); ?>`

*BASE_MEMBERS =* `<?php define('BASE_MEMBERS', BASE_URL . '/members/'); ?>`

Now what i need? To add class `act-link` to active page, i have 1 solution but i have some problems on subfolders. I will write example:

Note: **Config file**

```
$addClassActivePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$Home = "";
$Users = "";
$Contact = "";

swith($addClassActivePage) {
    case "index.php":
       $Home = "act-link";
       break;
    case "members/user.php":
        $Users = "act-link";
        break;
    case "contact.php":
        $Contact = "act-link";
        break;
}
```

Problem is with subfolders. They display `act-link` on index.php and contact.php pages, but on users page ( subfolder/page.php ) don't display. I think the problem is on define path or simular.

If JavaScript resolve this on correctly way, write it. Thanks all

Comment: You don't need to add **= (equality)** symbol after **case** statement.

Comment: I know, i make mistake here, i don't have = ( equality ) @user3088867

Comment: And basename function will take only file name, doesn't matter what long your path would be. You could try to use `$addClassActivePage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if you are not passing any $_GET parameters.

Comment: Not working, syntax error 'case' (T_CASE) @user3088867

Comment: Correct solution would be to use this line of code `parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH)`

Comment: Well, you made typo mistake again. Instead of **switch** you wrote **swith**.

Comment: I will try now your code, yes spell mistake @user3088867 thanks!

Comment: That code is working, thanks a lot! @user3088867

Comment: But when u have folder/folder/file.php that code will not work @user3088867

Answer (score 0):

I would resole it with JavaScript:

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php BASE_URL; ?>/index.php" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php BASE_MEMBERS; ?>/index.php" id="user">Users</a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php BASE_URL; ?>/contact.php" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And in the Config File:

```
$addClassActivePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$Home = "";
$Users = "";
$Contact = "";

switch($addClassActivePage) {
    case = "index.php":
        echo '<script>document.getElementById("home").className = "act-link";</script>';
        break;
    case = "members/user.php":
        echo '<script>document.getElementById("user").className = "act-link";</script>';
        break;
    case = "contact.php":
        echo '<script>document.getElementById("contact").className = "act-link";</script>';
        break;
}
```

So you only have to change few lines:
`class="<?php echo $Home; ?>"` to `id="home"`

`$Home = "act-link";` to `echo '<script>document.getElementById("home").className = "act-link";</script>';`

Comment: Don't work for me... I add ID to navigation like you write, and change config file, but don't work. Instead of ID i think need to add class because is used class not id? I'm i correct?

Answer (score 0):

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
basename — Returns trailing name component of path

always

```
basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

return the path after last slash  /
remove basename function and add / before member case in switch

```
basename()
```

solve the problem

config file :

```
$addClassActivePage =$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$Home = "";
$Users = "";
$Contact = "";

switch($addClassActivePage) {
        case "index.php":
       $Home = "act-link";
   break;
case "/members/user.php": // add / before members
    $Users = "act-link";
    break;
case "contact.php":
    $Contact = "act-link";
    break;
}
```

Comment: This not work, code that in your ide and try on localhost and you will see. Correct sollution for me is answer by @user3088867 ( And basename function will take only file name, doesn't matter what long your path would be. You could try to use $addClassActivePage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] if you are not passing any $_GET parameters.  )